# MongoDB with Spring Data how to conditionally upsert?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Currently trying to implement an update operation on MongoDB with Spring data.

```
public class Student {

        @Indexed(unique = true)
        @NotNull
        private String studentId;
        private Long triggerTime;
        ...
}
```

What I actually want to achieve is a **conditional upsert**. (update if exists/create if not based on studentId) as long as the triggerTime of the persisted student doc is older.

Read up on Configuring a `WriteConcernResolver` with `WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED` as follows :

```
public WriteConcern resolve(MongoAction action) {
    if (action.getCollectionName().getClass().getSimpleName().contains("Student")) {
        return WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED;
    }
    return action.getDefaultWriteConcern();
}
```

But I don´t understand the `MongoAction` object and how to create it. Or am I totally on the wrong track??

Answer (score 1):

You are confused a bit.

Write concern it's globally high-level connection configuration to define level of acknowledgment requested from MongoDB for `write` operations, such as `insert`, `update`, `remove`, etc...

In other words, your app tells MongoDB the minimal acknowledgment ([ACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acknowledgement_(data_networks))) expects from server.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/

---

[upsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-upsert) is a MongoDB update method's option to create a new document when no document matches the query criteria. By default is `false`, so when no documents matched, update condition is ignored. If it's `true`, it will create new document with fields defined in `query` + `update` parameters.

Take a look how it works:

```
//search a student
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("studentId").is("1"));

//update condition
Update update = new Update();
update.set("triggerTime", System.currentTimeMillis());

mongoOperation.upsert(query, update, Student.class);
```

It will try to match by `studentId`. 
- If do found, it will update `triggerTime` with current time.
- If not found, it will insert new document with `studentId:"1", triggerTime:current time` and other fields will be `null` (if `Student` class has more fields).

### Unfortunately, there is no conditional upsert running a single query.

You need to do it manually: Search - Apply business logic - create / save / ignore

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps, but it looks to me like the Mongo Update query (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) allows a "query" parameter which will affect which data it acts on.  If you write a query which is semantically `other.studentId NOT EXISTS OR (other.studentId EXISTS AND other.triggerTime < this.triggerTime)` and pass that query to your Mongo upsert action, that should solve your problem, right?